# Create a View which spans multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a view in MySQL which shows a Player's name, their Guardians name, their Guardians phone number and the team the Player plays in.

I have this script which creates the database :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TeamCoach;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TeamPlayer;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CoachQualification;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PlayerGuardian;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PersonAddress;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PersonPhoneNumber;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Coach;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Player;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Qualification;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Team;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PhoneNumber;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS School;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Person;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Address;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Guardian;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TeamSize;

CREATE TABLE Qualification (
qualificationID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
level int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (qualificationID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Team (
teamID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
ageGroup varchar(30) NOT NULL,
year int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (teamID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Address (
addressID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
number int NOT NULL,
street varchar(30) NOT NULL,
suburb varchar(30) NOT NULL,
townCity varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (addressID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PhoneNumber (
phoneNumberID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
number varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (phoneNumberID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE School (
schoolID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (schoolID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Person (
personID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
email varchar(30) NOT NULL,
photo varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (personID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PersonAddress (
personID int NOT NULL,
addressID int NOT NULL,
KEY personID (personID),
KEY addressID (addressID),
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Person (personID),
FOREIGN KEY (addressID) REFERENCES Address (addressID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PersonPhoneNumber (
personID int NOT NULL,
phoneNumberID int NOT NULL,
KEY personID (personID),
KEY phoneNumberID (phoneNumberID),
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Person (personID),
FOREIGN KEY (phoneNumberID) REFERENCES PhoneNumber (phoneNumberID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Coach (
coachID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Person (personID),
dateBeganCoaching varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Player (
playerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Person (personID),
DOB varchar(10) NOT NULL,
schoolID int NOT NULL,
KEY schoolID (schoolID),
FOREIGN KEY (schoolID) REFERENCES School (schoolID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Guardian (
guardianID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Person (personID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PlayerGuardian (
guardianID int NOT NULL,
playerID int NOT NULL,
KEY guardianID (guardianID),
KEY playerID (playerID),
FOREIGN KEY (guardianID) REFERENCES Guardian (guardianID),
FOREIGN KEY (playerID) REFERENCES Player (playerID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE TeamPlayer (
teamID int NOT NULL,
playerID int NOT NULL,
KEY teamID (teamID),
KEY playerID (playerID),
FOREIGN KEY (teamID) REFERENCES Team (teamID),
FOREIGN KEY (playerID) REFERENCES Player (playerID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE TeamCoach (
teamID int NOT NULL,
coachID int NOT NULL,
KEY teamID (teamID),
KEY coachID (coachID),
FOREIGN KEY (teamID) REFERENCES Team (teamID),
FOREIGN KEY (coachID) REFERENCES Coach (coachID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE CoachQualification (
coachID int NOT NULL,
qualificationID int NOT NULL,
KEY coachID (coachID),
KEY qualificationID (qualificationID),
FOREIGN KEY (coachID) REFERENCES Coach (coachID),
FOREIGN KEY (qualificationID) REFERENCES Qualification (qualificationID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION TeamSize(Team varchar(30))
RETURNS int
DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE Size int;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO Size FROM ((
SELECT * FROM TeamPlayer WHERE teamID=(
SELECT teamID FROM Team WHERE name='Red Bulls')))AS TeamSize;
RETURN Size;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And this script which fills it with data :

```
INSERT INTO Qualification (name, level) VALUES ('Under 7s', '3');
INSERT INTO Qualification (name, level) VALUES ('Under 8s', '1');
INSERT INTO Qualification (name, level) VALUES ('Under 9s', '5');
INSERT INTO Qualification (name, level) VALUES ('Under 10s', '4');
INSERT INTO Qualification (name, level) VALUES ('Under 80s', '10');

INSERT INTO Team (name, ageGroup, year) VALUES ('Blue Hawks', 'Under 7s', '2015');
INSERT INTO Team (name, ageGroup, year) VALUES ('Yellow Dolphins', 'Under 8s', '2013');
INSERT INTO Team (name, ageGroup, year) VALUES ('Red Bulls', 'Under 9s', '2014');
INSERT INTO Team (name, ageGroup, year) VALUES ('Turquiose Turtles', 'Under 10s', '2015');
INSERT INTO Team (name, ageGroup, year) VALUES ('Violet Butterflies', 'Under 80s', '2015');

INSERT INTO Address (number, street, suburb, townCity) VALUES ('6', 'Selwyn Street', 'North East Valley', 'Dunedin');
INSERT INTO Address (number, street, suburb, townCity) VALUES ('6', 'Inverleith Street', 'Woodhaugh', 'Dunedin');
INSERT INTO Address (number, street, suburb, townCity) VALUES ('40', 'Chaucer Street', 'Milton', 'Milton');
INSERT INTO Address (number, street, suburb, townCity) VALUES ('105', 'Inniscort Street', 'Decent Part', 'Cromwell');
INSERT INTO Address (number, street, suburb, townCity) VALUES ('43', 'Chambers Street', 'North East Valley', 'Dunedin');

INSERT INTO PhoneNumber (number) VALUES ('034178669');
INSERT INTO PhoneNumber (number) VALUES ('0272637393');
INSERT INTO PhoneNumber (number) VALUES ('0277147957');
INSERT INTO PhoneNumber (number) VALUES ('0220826217');
INSERT INTO PhoneNumber (number) VALUES ('0800838383');

INSERT INTO School (name) VALUES ('Tokomairiro High');
INSERT INTO School (name) VALUES ('Cromwell College');
INSERT INTO School (name) VALUES ('Otago Boys');
INSERT INTO School (name) VALUES ('Otago Girls');
INSERT INTO School (name) VALUES ('Woodhaugh Rest Palace');

INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Andrew Fletcher', 'gmail@gmail.com', 'puppy.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Sam Bates', 'outlook@outlook.com', 'kitten.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Mason Osbourne', 'yahoo@gmail.com', 'cheetah.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Zara DeMontgomery', 'hola@malware.com', 'elephant.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Reuben Crimp', 'norton@avg.com', 'dolphins.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Joy Gasson', 'example@example.com', 'owl.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Brian Treanor', 'www@www.com', 'whale.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Dale Parsons', 'java@oracle.com', 'swordfish.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Tom Clark', 'GNU@linux.com', 'lion.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Jim Beam', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Jack Daniels', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('John Snow', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Ned Stark', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Tywin Lannister', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Hodor Hodor', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Joe Bloggs', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('John Doe', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Jane Doe', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Lassie Dog', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');
INSERT INTO Person (name, email, photo) VALUES ('Jake Sully', 'mysql@databases.com', 'monkey.jpg');

INSERT INTO PersonAddress (personID, addressID) VALUES ('1', '3');
INSERT INTO PersonAddress (personID, addressID) VALUES ('2', '4');
INSERT INTO PersonAddress (personID, addressID) VALUES ('3', '5');
INSERT INTO PersonAddress (personID, addressID) VALUES ('4', '3');
INSERT INTO PersonAddress (personID, addressID) VALUES ('5', '2');

INSERT INTO PersonPhoneNumber (personID, phoneNumberID) VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO PersonPhoneNumber (personID, phoneNumberID) VALUES ('2', '4');
INSERT INTO PersonPhoneNumber (personID, phoneNumberID) VALUES ('3', '1');
INSERT INTO PersonPhoneNumber (personID, phoneNumberID) VALUES ('4', '5');
INSERT INTO PersonPhoneNumber (personID, phoneNumberID) VALUES ('5', '3');

INSERT INTO Coach (coachID, dateBeganCoaching) VALUES ('6', '2014');
INSERT INTO Coach (coachID, dateBeganCoaching) VALUES ('7', '2013');
INSERT INTO Coach (coachID, dateBeganCoaching) VALUES ('8', '2012');
INSERT INTO Coach (coachID, dateBeganCoaching) VALUES ('9', '2014');
INSERT INTO Coach (coachID, dateBeganCoaching) VALUES ('10', '1993');

INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, schoolID) VALUES ('1', '08/07/1993', '1');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, schoolID) VALUES ('2', '02/06/1993', '2');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, schoolID) VALUES ('3', '08/04/1995', '1');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, schoolID) VALUES ('4', '08/01/1994', '1');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, schoolID) VALUES ('5', '25/12/1992', '5');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, SchoolID) VALUES ('11', '06/07/1998', '3');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, SchoolID) VALUES ('12', '06/07/1998', '3');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, SchoolID) VALUES ('13', '06/07/1998', '4');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, SchoolID) VALUES ('14', '06/07/1998', '5');
INSERT INTO Player (playerID, DOB, SchoolID) VALUES ('15', '06/07/1998', '4');

INSERT INTO Guardian (guardianID) VALUES ('16');
INSERT INTO Guardian (guardianID) VALUES ('17');
INSERT INTO Guardian (guardianID) VALUES ('18');
INSERT INTO Guardian (guardianID) VALUES ('19');
INSERT INTO Guardian (guardianID) VALUES ('20');

INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('16', '1');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('16', '2');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('17', '3');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('17', '4');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('18', '5');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('18', '11');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('19', '12');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('19', '13');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('20', '14');
INSERT INTO PlayerGuardian (guardianID, playerID) VALUES ('20', '15');

INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('2', '2');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('3', '3');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('4', '4');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('5', '5');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('2', '11');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('4', '12');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('4', '13');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('3', '14');
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer (teamID, playerID) VALUES ('5', '15');

INSERT INTO TeamCoach (teamID, coachID) VALUES ('1', '6');
INSERT INTO TeamCoach (teamID, coachID) VALUES ('2', '7');
INSERT INTO TeamCoach (teamID, coachID) VALUES ('3', '8');
INSERT INTO TeamCoach (teamID, coachID) VALUES ('4', '9');
INSERT INTO TeamCoach (teamID, coachID) VALUES ('5', '10');

INSERT INTO CoachQualification (coachID, qualificationID) VALUES ('6', '5');
INSERT INTO CoachQualification (coachID, qualificationID) VALUES ('7', '4');
INSERT INTO CoachQualification (coachID, qualificationID) VALUES ('8', '3');
INSERT INTO CoachQualification (coachID, qualificationID) VALUES ('9', '2');
INSERT INTO CoachQualification (coachID, qualificationID) VALUES ('10', '1');
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. First try to write the query you want. Then use it to create the view

Comment: Can a player have multiple guardians?

Comment: A player can have multiple guardians and a guardian can have multiple players.

Comment: So how do you want it formatted? If a player has two guardians, if it shows 2 rows, a player will be in there twice. If you're pulling from a database, then a [`many to many`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations) relationship should really be done in two queries. I recommend checking out an `ORM` that will handle the logic for you like [CakePHP's](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've attempted to create a query that will work for your data, but this is assuming you only have one guardian for each player (Which you said in your comment that this is not possible). [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16e7b/12) is the SQLFiddle if you want to play around with it a bit more.

```
SELECT p.name, pg.name AS `GuardianName`, pgpn.`number` AS `GuardianNumber`
FROM `Player` play
LEFT JOIN `Person` p ON play.playerID = p.personID
LEFT JOIN `PlayerGuardian` g ON play.playerID = g.playerID
LEFT JOIN `Person` pg ON g.guardianID = pg.personID
LEFT JOIN `PersonPhoneNumber` pgppn ON pg.personID = pgppn.personID
LEFT JOIN `PhoneNumber` pgpn ON pgpn.phoneNumberID = pgppn.phoneNumberID
```

The problem you're having is, how do you display multiple guardians for each player? Do you want players to show up multiple times for each guardian that player has? Then you have to worry about grouping coding level, and this can be a big hassle.

**My recommendation**: Use an [`ORM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) similar to [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html) that will do the heavy lifting for you. You set up the relationships between the tables, and it will do the magic of linking them up for you, in multiple efficient queries.

Comment: This works perfectly. Why use a LEFT JOIN over any other JOIN?

Comment: You can see the differences in join's [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Click through each chapter to see the different joins, and how they're useful. LEFT JOIN basically attempts to join data from the alternate table, and if it doesn't exist, it returns null data instead. Be aware, this query does not take into account multiple guardians (It will return only one row in this case).